# How to Receive JMS mesage from Queue and transform to SOAP using java

Tags: java, soap-client

I have written some code for getting message and transforming it into SOAP message.But here the compiler is not executing the next line of `SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageTransformer.SOAPMessageFromJMSMessage(bytesMessage, messageFactory);`

Can anyone let me know where i am wrong or what need to be done for transform the JMS message to SOAP.

Comment: You have not provided much details.  To get response/answer, you should add more details/code/exceptions etc.

Comment: Providing a little more code would really help...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to create a soap message manually if you're receiving a jms message?

I would reconsider your architecture and would do a SOAP over JMS implementation even if this is not my favorite design pattern :

https://dzone.com/articles/apache-cxf-23-implementation